# Having trouble with JSON and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make a simple sample previewer for my client project.
The list of samples are stored in a JSON file. but the trouble is that I am not too familiar with using JSON, or programming itself, to be honest.
I have written a short test code to see if this JSON file works well, but although I can access `sampleData` variable from firebug console, the `document.write(sampleData.length);` line seems to be unable to access `sampleData` for some reason. The error shows:

> TypeError: sampleData is undefined

I suspect it has to do with variable scopes, but I am not sure.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sampleData;
    $.getJSON('res/Samples.json',function(data){
        sampleData=data;
    });
    document.write(sampleData.length);
</script>
```

**What should I do to make the `sampleData` variable to work with the rest of the code?**
I'm sorry I cannot disclose the contents of the json file. It contains an array of objects containing information of the products. it looks like

```
[
    {
    "aaa" : 000000;
    },
    {
    "bbb" : 111111;
    },
    {
    "ccc" : 222222;
    }
]
```

It's a quite generic form of JSON file, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code's fine, but `$.getJSON` just **starts** the process of getting the JSON file, and then allows your code to continue, calling `document.write`. The callback to `$.getJSON` is called **later**, **after** your `document.write` call. Instead, trigger any subsequent code you want to trigger from **within** the callback.

You can't usefully use `document.write` in this situation. You can use the DOM, though, and jQuery's various DOM wrapper functions. For instance:

```
$.getJSON('res/Samples.json',function(data){
    $("<p>").html(data.length).appendTo(document.body);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using ajax statement with async parameter instead...I know it sort of breaks the meaning of ajax, but whatever... :)

Comment: @K.H.: More importantly, it locks up the UI of the browser while the request is in progress, making for a poor UX. If at all possible, embrace the asynchronousness. :-) But I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the async response from `$.getJSON`.

```
var sampleData;
$.getJSON('res/Samples.json', function(data) {
  sampleData = data; // This is occurring after the document.write
});
document.write(sampleData.length);
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
var sampleData;
setTimeout(function() {
  sampleData = 'Some data'; // This is occurring after the document.write
}, 100);
document.write(sampleData.length);
```

You *could* move the `document.write` to the response handler but as noted below it does have its [drawbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

```
var sampleData;
$.getJSON('res/Samples.json', function(data) {
  document.write(sampleData.length); // This would replace the page contents
});
```

Comment: *"You could move the document.write to the response handler:"* You *could*, but it would wipe out the content of the page and replace it with just that number. After initial parsing, using `document.write` implicitly calls `document.open`, wiping out the page.

Comment: True, but that's a different problem. Best way to learn how things work is to see how they break. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the document.write thing. I tried that before I came back to this post, and had to learn it the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

It happens asynchronously, so you need to call `document.write` in the async call itself:

```
var sampleData;
$.getJSON('res/Samples.json',function(data){
    sampleData = data;
    document.write(sampleData.length);
});
```

Also, if you're using `document.write` in your production code to write to the page, I would suggest against it. If you used `document.write` in the above example just for debugging purposes (to figure out why it wasn't working), I would suggest using `console.log` instead. Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is an async function and when you do `document.write(sampleData.length);`, `sampleData` is not populated yet.

You must to do:

```
$.getJSON('res/Samples.json',function(data){
   sampleData=data;
   document.write(sampleData.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well is reason is you call the `sampleData.length` before the ajax call return the values you need to put the document.write(sampleData.length); inside the ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sampleData;
    $.getJSON('res/Samples.json',function(data){
        sampleData=data;
        document.write(sampleData.length);
    });

</script>
```